# What statement can b rolled back in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL we can disable the autocommit feature, so statements must be explicitly commited to the database, This is (should be) nice because we can rollback (undo) operations if we screwed up something badly.

Here is the my problem what I faced, deleted tables cannot rolled back (meaning the table is gone for good)

My Question is what kind of Statements exactly can rolled back?

```
mysql> SELECT @@autocommit;
    +--------------+
    | @@autocommit |
    +--------------+
    |            1 |
    +--------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
    
mysql> SET @@autocommit = 0;
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
    
mysql> SELECT @@autocommit;
    +--------------+
    | @@autocommit |
    +--------------+
    |            0 |                                     // autocommit disabled 
    +--------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
    
mysql> DROP TABLE testTable;                             // deleting the testTable 
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
    
mysql> ROLLBACK;                                         // rollback commit  
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
    
mysql> TABLE testTable;                                  // testTable deleted (DROP TABLE statement is not rolled back)
    ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'testDB.testTable' doesn't exist
mysql>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL documents [Statements That Cause an Implicit Commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html). In general these include anything that defines or modifies database objects (tables, functions, triggers, views, indexes... anything with a `create` statement) like `create <thing>`, `alter <thing>` and `drop <thing>`.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but AFAIR I saw somewhere that the rows loaded by **failed** LOAD DATA INFILE were not removed during rollback...

Comment: @Akina That would be easy enough to test. Let us know.